# Create automated report from web data

Tags: excel, ms-access, automation

I have a set of multiple API's I need to source data from and need four different data categories. This data is then used for reporting purposes in Excel.

I initially created web queries in Excel, but my Laptop just crashes because there is too many querie which have to be updated. Do you guys know a smart workaround?

This is an example of the API I will source data from (40 different ones in total)
https://api.similarweb.com/SimilarWebAddon/id.priceprice.com/all
The data points I need are:

```
EstimatedMonthlyVisits, TopOrganicKeywords, OrganicSearchShare, TrafficSources
```

Any ideas how I can create an automated report which queries the above data on request?

Thanks so much.

Comment: Start typing code.

Answer (score 0):

If Excel is crashing due to the demand, and that doesn't surprise me, you should consider using Python or R for this task.

```
install.packages("XML")
install.packages("plyr")
install.packages("ggplot2")
install.packages("gridExtra")

require("XML")
require("plyr")
require("ggplot2")
require("gridExtra")
```

Next we need to set our working directory and parse the XML file as a matter of practice, so we're sure that R can access the data within the file. This is basically reading the file into R. Then, just to confirm that R knows our file is in XML, we check the class. Indeed, R is aware that it's XML.

```
setwd("C:/Users/Tobi/Documents/R/InformIT") #you will need to change the filepath on  your machine
xmlfile=xmlParse("pubmed_sample.xml")
class(xmlfile) #"XMLInternalDocument" "XMLAbstractDocument"
```

Now we can begin to explore our XML. Perhaps we want to confirm that our HTTP query on Entrez pulled the correct results, just as when we query PubMed's website. We start by looking at the contents of the first node or root, PubmedArticleSet. We can also find out how many child nodes the root has and their names. This process corresponds to checking how many entries are in the XML file. The root's child nodes are all named PubmedArticle.

```
xmltop = xmlRoot(xmlfile) #gives content of root
class(xmltop)#"XMLInternalElementNode" "XMLInternalNode" "XMLAbstractNode"
xmlName(xmltop) #give name of node, PubmedArticleSet
xmlSize(xmltop) #how many children in node, 19
xmlName(xmltop[[1]]) #name of root's children
```

To see the first two entries, we can do the following.

```
# have a look at the content of the first child entry
xmltop[[1]]
# have a look at the content of the 2nd child entry
xmltop[[2]]
```

Our exploration continues by looking at subnodes of the root. As with the root node, we can list the name and size of the subnodes as well as their attributes. In this case, the subnodes are MedlineCitation and PubmedData.

```
#Root Node's children
xmlSize(xmltop[[1]]) #number of nodes in each child
xmlSApply(xmltop[[1]], xmlName) #name(s)
xmlSApply(xmltop[[1]], xmlAttrs) #attribute(s)
xmlSApply(xmltop[[1]], xmlSize) #size
```

We can also separate each of the 19 entries by these subnodes. Here we do so for the first and second entries:

```
#take a look at the MedlineCitation subnode of 1st child
xmltop[[1]][[1]]
#take a look at the PubmedData subnode of 1st child
xmltop[[1]][[2]]

#subnodes of 2nd child
xmltop[[2]][[1]]
xmltop[[2]][[2]]
```

The separation of entries is really just us, indexing into the tree structure of the XML. We can continue to do this until we exhaust a path—or, in XML terminology, reach the end of the branch. We can do this via the numbers of the child nodes or their actual names:

```
#we can keep going till we reach the end of a branch
xmltop[[1]][[1]][[5]][[2]] #title of first article
xmltop[['PubmedArticle']][['MedlineCitation']][['Article']][['ArticleTitle']] #same command, but more readable
```

Finally, we can transform the XML into a more familiar structure—a dataframe. Our command completes with errors due to non-uniform formatting of data and nodes. So we must check that all the data from the XML is properly inputted into our dataframe. Indeed, there are duplicate rows, due to the creation of separate rows for tag attributes. For instance, the ELocationID node has two attributes, ValidYN and EIDType. Take the time to note how the duplicates arise from this separation.

```
#Turning XML into a dataframe

    Madhu2012=ldply(xmlToList("pubmed_sample.xml"), data.frame) #completes with errors: "row names were found from a short variable and have been discarded"
    View(Madhu2012) #for easy checking that the data is properly formatted
    Madhu2012.Clean=Madhu2012[Madhu2012[25]=='Y',] #gets rid of duplicated rows
```

Here is a link that should help you get started.

http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2215520

If you have never used R before, it will take a little getting used to, but it's worth it.  I've been using it for a few years now and when compared to Excel, I have seen R perform anywhere from a couple hundred percent faster to many thousands of percent faster than Excel.  Good luck.